# SaveChangesAsync not working inside PUT method

Tags: c#, odata, put

I am Using ODataController to insert and Update Entries to Database
I am hitting the PUT method , using .UpdateEntryAsync()

Here is my  Put Method.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] string key, Delta<KYCBtnDetails> patch)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

                KYCBtnDetails KYCBtnDetails = await _KYCDBModel.KYCBtnDetails.FindAsync(key);
                if (KYCBtnDetails == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                patch.Put(KYCBtnDetails);
                KYCBtnDetails.id = key;

                try
                {
                    await _KYCDBModel.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }

                return Updated(KYCBtnDetails);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return null;
        }
```

on await _KYCDBModel.SaveChangesAsync() it give me error as
"New Transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session"
"An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details."

Sometimes it runs and sometimes it gives error

Please Help me on this,
Thank You.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Short answer - `_KYCDBModel` is likely registered wrong.

Comment: It looks like the questions seeks more details

Comment: 99.99% this is because of sharing `_KYCDBModel` between several requests.

Comment: Agree with Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention, here's how the `Put` controller action signature is expected to look like:

```cs
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] string key, [FromBody]KYCBtnDetails kycBtnDetails)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you decide to use `Patch`, here is how the controller action signature is expected to look like:

```cs
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] string key, [FromBody]Delta<KYCBtnDetails> patch)
{
    // ...
}
```

Take specific note of `FromBody` attribute